# Multiple pv order

Tags: bash, shell-script, pv

I have a script on a Linux machine with a fancy pv piped to a second pv that count a subset of the outputted lines.

Here's the script:

```bsh
max=1000
for (( i=0; i<max; i++ )); do
  [[ $(shuf -i 1-100 -n 1) -lt 20 ]] && echo REMOVE || echo LEAVE
done | pv -F "%N %b / $(numfmt --to=si $max) %t %p %e" -c -N 'Lookups' -l -s $max \
  | grep --line-buffered '^REMOVE' \
  | pv -F "%N %b / $(numfmt --to=si $max)" -c -N 'Deletes' -l -s $max \
  >/dev/null
stty sane
```

what I would expect is that the first pv always shows first, and the second always second.

Like this example output:

```bsh
$ ./fancy_pv.sh
  Lookups: 1.00k / 1.0K 0:00:03 [===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================>] 100%            
  Deletes:  189  / 1.0K
```

But that's not the case, sometimes they swap positions and I see something like this:

```bsh
$ ./fancy_pv.sh
  Deletes:  199  / 1.0K
  Lookups: 1.00k / 1.0K 0:00:03 [===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================>] 100%
```

And sometimes I also see something like this:

```bsh
$ ./fancy_pv.sh
  Lookups:  321  / 1.0K 0:00:01 [===============================================================================================================>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ] 32% ETA 0:00:02
  Deletes:  198  / 1.0K
  Lookups: 1.00k / 1.0K 0:00:03 [===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================>] 100%
```

I know it must be because of the way pv deletes the line and redraws it, but is there anything I can do to prevent it from messing with the order?

`stty sane` is there to sanitize the prompt because sometimes pv leaves the terminal unusable.

Thanks

Comment: You didn't mention what shell you are using, but since you have `[[` I assumed bash and tagged accordingly. Please change it if that is wrong

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I use bash.
I don't know how `screen` or `tmux` can be used here, hopefully someone can help us figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two `pv` processes in the pipe may start in any order. The output from the latest `pv` will be in the bottom line.

Delay `pv` you want in the bottom line. Instead of `pv …` (where `…` denotes all its arguments) use a subshell:

```
( </dev/null sleep 1; exec pv … )
```

In theory the other `pv` may still start after the delayed one, but in a not-totally-overloaded system it's almost certain the delayed `pv` will start last.

`sleep` should not read from its stdin anyway; `</dev/null` is in case your `sleep` is weird.

I'm not sure if some race condition can cause an extra (stale) line to appear. If so, delaying one `pv` should also (almost certainly) help. In my tests the output gets mangled when the terminal needs to be "additionally" updated. Therefore:

- Do not resize the terminal while `pv`s are running.
- Avoid scrolling:

  - Before you run the script, invoke `clear` (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>). This will clear the screen, place the prompt on top and provide room below without the need of scrolling later.
  - Do not type while `pv`s are running; especially multiple <kbd>Enter</kbd>s (that could eventually scroll the text) should be avoided.
  - In general do not let anything else than `pv`s print to the terminal until `pv`s finish. This applies to other parts of the pipe (e.g. via `/dev/tty`), asynchronous processes in the script (e.g. simply via their stdout), processes outside of the script (e.g. via `/dev/tty*` or `/dev/pts/*`).

Comment: Very practical solution. I expected `pv` to do this by itself somehow but neither `pv --wait` nor `pv --delay-start` seem to work reliably for a longer `pv` chain. Well, this output mode is a bit of a hack.

Comment: The delay works really well, when you suggested the subshell I also came out with another idea, this is what I ended up with:
`| tee >(</dev/null sleep 1; grep --line-buffered '^REMOVE' | pv -F "%N %b / $(numfmt --to=si $max)" -c -N 'Deletes' -l -s $max >/dev/null)`
using tee allows me to append more pv to count other lines without altering the output.